# ksh prompt defined as function with newlines

Tags: shell, git, ksh

I wrote myself a pretty, git aware ksh prompt function. Here I only include a minimal working example so that you can see my problem without all the bloat:

```
#!/bin/ksh

function _test_prompt
{
    prompt="`whoami`@`hostname` > "
    [[ $(id -u) -eq 0 ]] && prompt="ROOT@`hostname` # "

    print "\n\w"
    print -n "$prompt"
}

export readonly PS1='$(_test_prompt)'
```

I source this script from my `.kshrc`.

The problem is that when I try to look at for example a longer, prettified git log, the prompt's newlines cut off the top of my output. For example

```
git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s'
```

shows up as

```
* f0490d0 - Make sure fb is big enough to handle reconfigure   (3 years, 10 months ago) <Keith Packard>
* 7caa6ce - Add xrandr-auto sample script   (3 years, 10 months ago) <Keith Packard>
* f59c924 - (tag: v0.2) Update to version 0.2   (7 years ago) <Keith Packard>
* a6c8969 - Add --auto switch, a shortcut for --config "xrandr --auto"   (7 years ago) <Keith Packard>
* d45135b - Add manual   (7 years ago) <Keith Packard>
* ef165dc - add .gitignore   (7 years ago) <Keith Packard>
* d927ec1 - Autotool   (7 years ago) <Keith Packard>
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~
~

~/git-misc/x-on-resize
user@hostname >
```

And the first line of the output can only be seen by paging up once:

```
~/git-misc/x-on-resize
user@hostname > git log --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s'
* 617e5ed - (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) Use mode ID instead of mode for autoconfig   (3 years, 10 months ago) <Keith Packard>
* f0490d0 - Make sure fb is big enough to handle reconfigure   (3 years, 10 months ago) <Keith Packard>
```

(this is what's at the bottom of the previous page, cut off).

As you can imagine, this is very annoying; in this case I actually lose the most recent commit and have to scroll up for it.

This only happens when the output of the log would fit on one screen (otherwise it goes into less).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you confirmed that this is actually happening due to the _prompt_ and nothing else?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, without changing PS1 things work just fine. The reason must be the newlines in the prompt. When I remove the `\n` before the pwd line and add the `-n` switch to that `print`, the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, I managed to solve the problem after I actually got around to ask about it.

I simply set the `pager.log` git config variable to `less -RFc`; the relevant switch is `-c` as far as I understand: it tells `less` to repaint the screen from bottom to top instead of doing so vice versa.

Apprently, this was indeed not a ksh issue. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution as an answer